# How to start a service from a service on android?

Tags: android, android-intent, service

I have a service and i want to start an other service from it. How can i do this? 
This is from the developer.android.com and it gives me a NullPointerException. Is there an other way to do this?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, HelloService.class);
startService(intent);
```

I found only starting activity from a service like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClass(this, MyActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```

Maybe i need to use this code and flag the service somehow?

Comment: and from where (in service) you are starting next service?

Comment: In the service, a ServerSocket reads data from a client, and if the data equals with something, i can make the service to do something. That is where i want to start an other service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/LJkmfdy5SXE

It works to use a fully-qualified class name when starting a service in another application:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClassName("com.backgroundService", "com.backgroundService.MyService");
startService(i);
```